# query that outputs that # of unique records per field in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given a Model like:

```
Contact (id, user_id, xxx, xxxxxxx)
```

I would like to have a query that outputs that # of unique user_id records in the Contact model? Any thoughts on how to write this?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM contacts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this in SQL, but if you want to try to keep within the ORM provided by ActiveRecord as much as possible I think the following is the closest you are going to get:

```
@user_ids = Contact.select('DISTINCT user_id').all
```

`@user_ids` will then be an array of all the user ids referenced from records in the contact table. If you want to know how many there are you can just call `@user_ids.count`.

---

**Update**: Another way of doing this that provides even more information without the overhead of instantiating each object and avoids writing SQL is as follows:

```
Contact.group('user_id').count  #=> { 1 => 3, 2 => 4, 3 => 10 }
```

As you can see, the response is a hash with the user ids as keys and the quantity for each user as the value. You can get the number of unique user ids with another `.count`:

```
Contact.group('user_id').count.count  #=> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternative ways to do it:

```
Contact.count('user_id', :distinct => true)
# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "contacts"."user_id") FROM "contacts"

Contact.count('DISTINCT user_id')
# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM "contacts"
```

Comment: Oh nice! I didn't realize `count` accepted any arguments. Doh!

Comment: Turns out there's a more API-ish way to do it, which is using the `:distinct => true` option.